# Как правильнее сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Как правильно: "внесите результаты измерения плотности в таблицу" ИЛИ "внесите результаты измерения **значений** плотности в таблицу"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется верно так: внесите результаты измерения плотности в таблицу или измерьте плотность и полученные значения внесите в таблицу. Но причем здесь март?

Comment: Март всегда месяц, значит, МАРТ - лишнее слово. 
Измеряем плотность, результат вносим в таблицу, ЗНАЧЕНИЕ тоже в какой-то степени лишнее слово :)

Answer (score 0):

"Значений" действительно лишнее. Причем в нашем случае это даже не стилистическая ошибка, а смысловая. Измеряют не значения, а саму физическую величину.
Значения - результат измерения.

Поэтому выбирать (если уж выбирать) надо из ваотантов:
~ внесите результаты измерения плотности в таблицу
и
~ внесите значений результаты измерения плотности в таблицу.

Совершенно очевидно, что во втором случае "значения" избыточно.